# Why the first SetState always affected and the second not in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am using setState inside componentDidMount() to set the state of the same variables but I realise that the first setState is always affected and variables take the values defined on the first setState. I want the second to overwrite the first and give the variables the values of the second setState. Even if I change the order the same result.  Why does this happen?
To be precise I am speaking about the latitude and longitude variables.

```
  componentDidMount() {

    fetch('myUrl')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        Geocoder.setApiKey('myUrl');
        Geocoder.getFromLocation(responseJson.comune_nascita).then(
          json => {
            var location = json.results[0].geometry.location;
            this.setState({
              Load:false,
              latitude:location.lat,
              longitude:location.lng
            })

          },

            error => {
              alert(error);
            }
          );
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });


        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
        error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccurancy: false, timeout: 2000, maximumage: 2000 }
      );
   }
```

Comment: Please correctly format your code, it'll make it easier and clearer to read and understand for anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to indicate that the "first setState" is the setState called in the fetch request and the "second setState" is the setState called in the getCurrentPosition method of navigator. According to this I have some answers and suggestions.

This is a problem with your code being ***asynchronous***. As you can see the fetch is called and then **once it is complete** it will set the state to whatever the latitude and longitude is. The second call is not an ***asynchronous*** call, it is called as soon as componentDidMount is called.

Essentially, the second setState call is actually getting called first as soon as the component mounts AND THEN the first setState overwrites it once the fetch is completed.

To fix this I would suggest restructuring your methodology of how this feature will work. The asynchronous call will always finish second and therefore you may want to switch what your default values are.